# What is the algorithm for the CHINZO-72C encoding? Reverse engineer it or try to reveal php's source code?

Tags: php, algorithm, encoding

According to this website: http://crypo.in.ua/tools/eng_chinzo-72c.php it encodes plaintext into a Chinese character cipher.

I couldn't find any information about it's algorithm, is there a way to reverse engineer this encoding or the PHP page's source code?

For example:

```
a
```

encodes to

```
法 吴
```

and

```
aa
```

encodes to

```
法 法 吴
```

and

```
aab
```

encodes to

```
法 法 弗 吴
```

Hmm actually, I think it's really easy to decode this... But I am not sure why the page says "Can not decrypt the Chinese characters of which was not encrypted by this script."

Comment: " " (just the space) encodes to 题 防 呒 吴 "a a" (without the quotes again) encodes to 法 题 防 呒 法 吴

Comment: I guess 吴 is always used to end the line. 题 防 呒 吴 is always the space and 法 is always "a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is just a simple substitution cipher:

```
a = 法
b = 弗
c = 朗
d = 斯
e = 伐
...
A = 呢
...
+ = 题 防 命
 (just a 1 character space) = 题 防 呒
(End of Line) = 吴
...
0 = 呒
```